# Не могу использовать автоинкремент

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, обработка-данных

По гайдам пытался добавить в свой скрипт автоинкремент, но он почему то требует передать столбец `id`, но в гайдах я такого нет.

Как можно сделать правильно?

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
sql = db.cursor()
sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT
)""")
db.commit()

user_login = input("Login: ")
user_passwd = input("Password: ")

sql.execute("SELECT login FROM users")
if sql.fetchone() is None:
    sql.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)", (user_login, user_passwd) )
    db.commit()
else:
    print("Такая запись уже есть")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст сообщения об ошибке:

> OperationalError: table users has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Надо явно указать, что вы делаете вставку в два столбца, чтобы число значений в `VALUES(...)` соответствовало числу столбцов указанных в скобках после имени таблицы:

```
sql.execute("INSERT INTO users(login, password) VALUES (?,?)", 
            (user_login, user_passwd))
```

PS если после имени таблицы не указаны столбцы (в скобках), в которые мы вставляем данные, то по умолчанию берутся **все** столбцы таблицы.